# How can i enable priority queues in ActiveMQ programmatically?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, priority-queue

I want to use priority message queues with ActiveMQ.
According to this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html) it is disabled by default.
I am using an embedded MessageBroker. Is it possible to enable priority programmatically. I don't have such a xml configuration file.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are embedding using plain java?

You should try something like this:

```
BrokerService bs = new BrokerService();
    bs.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    PolicyMap pm = new PolicyMap();
    PolicyEntry pe = new PolicyEntry();
    pe.setPrioritizedMessages(true);
    pm.setDefaultEntry(pe);
    bs.setDestinationPolicy(pm);
    bs.start();
```

if you are using spring to embedd your ActiveMQ, then notice that the activemq.xml in the ActiveMQ dist. is nothing but a simple spring context file that creates a broker with various properties.